# Buddhist practice in Singapore

Tags: east-asian-buddhism

Which are the major sects of Buddhism in Singapore? Which are these sects' main temples in Singapore?

Comment: I'm not sure if we allow such open-ended questions... we're really better equipped to deal with questions that have a single "right" answer...

Comment: I have edited the question so that it gets closer to having a single right answer. There is still some ambiguity as my question uses the terms "major" and "main." I hope that extent of ambiguity is acceptable.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to try the following as I have been attended some events there too :

http://www.fpmtabc.org/ - More to Tibetan Buddhism
https://www.facebook.com/buddhistlifemission
http://www.buddhistfellowship.org/cms/ - More to Theravada
http://www.kmspks.org/

Hope this helps. =)

Answer (score 1):

According to Peter Harvey in An [Introduction to Buddhism](http://books.google.co.uk/books/about/An_Introduction_to_Buddhism.html?id=bj-ds_jd8QYC) (second edition page 413)

> 43% of people in Singapore practice some form of Buddhism; mainly
>   Chinese Mahayana but also some Thai Theravada or Japanese Soka Gakkai
>   and more recently Tibetan Buddhism.

Hope that's of some interest.

Answer (score 0):

There are Wikipedia articles for [about 30 of the Buddhist temples in Singapore](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Buddhist_temples#Singapore).